# Binary Trees Changing Node vs Changing Value of Nodes

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Confused about the pros/cons of moving the entire node vs just changing values in the node when modifying a binary tree. In the specific question, we have to delete the root and than replace it with the successor. The follow-up question: "An alternate way of moving successor is by simply changing the value in the node, rather than moving entire node. In general when is it more appropriate to use each of the two methods and why?"

Only thing I could think of is changing only value is more simple, but maybe it wouldn't work if node has outside references